# WiFi adapter won't enable in a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 on my sister's Dell Inspiron 3521. After installing I noticed that the WiFi adapter won't turn on. I could see a `Enable WiFi` option on the tray icon but when I check that nothing happens. When I do an `lspci` I see this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

I also checked in my BIOS to see if its disabled through that but I couldn't even find an option there to do that.

When I try `rfkill list all` I see:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

I'm guessing this is the reason why its not working. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a hard (button) wifi  turn-off switch?

Comment: Nope, I do not.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 3521 don't have a hard button but maybe you turn WiFi off by pressing Fn + F2. It's unlikely but you can [update BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Fn + F2 worked. I'm such a doofus. I didn't realize that those would work here as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @electrophile don't worry, you learn something new :) I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dell Inspiron 3521](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/diagnose) don't have a hard button to turn WiFi off/on.

Instead toggle by pressing <kbd>Fn + F2</kbd>:

[image: image of the keyboard]

The output of `rfkill list all` you provided is particularly useful to detect the problem wasn't elsewhere.